# tcpdf: get form data

Tags: php, forms, pdf, tcpdf, modx

I'm running Modx cms and created an eform. I would like user to be able to download a pdf with a filled form. I already know how to create a pdf from a normal text on the page using tcpdf but because of my poor programming skills, I have no idea how to pass form data to pdf.
Is there any easy solution? I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Look into eForm's event handler eFormOnBeforeMailSent. It may not be available in old versions of eForm. So make sure you use a current version. You find the eForm documentation in te snippet folder (/assets/snippets/eform) of your MODx installation.

This link may help you, also: http://www.partout.info/example_onbeforemailsent.html